# Only allowing octal numbers

Tags: c, octal

What my code does is:

- User selects either a conversion from decimal to octal or octal to decimal.
- User puts in a number
- User gets result of conversion

Now i want to only allow otcal numbers when converting from octal to decimal and give out a error message if the number isn't octal.
How can this be achieved?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int UmrechnungDezimalZuOktal(int dezimalzahl), UmrechnungOktalZuDezimal(int oktalzahl);
int main()
{
    char auswahl;
    int dezimalzahl, oktalzahl, nichtBeendet = 1, c;
    

    while (nichtBeendet) {
            printf("\n\n  ##################  AUSWAHL  ##################\n"
                "  #                                             #\n"
                "  #     1) Konvertierung Dezimal -> Oktal       #\n"
                "  #     2) Konvertierung Oktal -> Dezimal       #\n"
                "  #     3) Abbruch                              #\n"
                "  #                                             #\n"
                "  ###############################################\n\n");

            printf("Auswahl: ");
            scanf("%c", &auswahl);

            switch (auswahl) {
            case '1': {                                                                                      /* Konvertierung Dezimal -> Oktal */
                printf("Geben Sie eine positive, ganze Dezimalzahl ein: ");
                scanf("%d", &dezimalzahl);

                if (dezimalzahl >= 0)
                {
                printf("Die Dezimalzahl %d entspricht der Oktalzahl %d", dezimalzahl, UmrechnungDezimalZuOktal(dezimalzahl));
                }
                else
                {
                printf("Bitte nur positive Zahlen eingeben!");
                }
                break;
            }
            case '2': {                                                                                      /* Konvertierung Oktal-> Dezimal */
                printf("Geben Sie eine positive, ganze Oktalzahl ein: ");
                scanf("%d", &oktalzahl);

                if (oktalzahl >= 0)
                {
                printf("Die Oktalzahl %d entspricht der Dezimalzahl %d", oktalzahl, UmrechnungOktalZuDezimal(oktalzahl));
                 }
                else
                {
                    printf("Bitte nur positive Zahlen eingeben!");
                }
                break;

            }
            case '3': {                                                                                      /* Abbruch */
                nichtBeendet = 0;
                break;
            }
            default: {                                                                                       /* Ungültige Eingabe*/
                printf("Ungueltige Eingabe!");
                break;
            }
            }
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {};
        }
}

int UmrechnungDezimalZuOktal(int dezimalzahl)                                                               /* Rechnung Dezimal -> Oktal */                                                         
{
    int oktalzahl = 0, i = 1;

    while (dezimalzahl != 0)
    {
        oktalzahl += (dezimalzahl % 8) * i;
        dezimalzahl /= 8;
        i *= 10;
    }

    return oktalzahl;
} 

int UmrechnungOktalZuDezimal(int oktalzahl)                                                                 /* Rechnung Oktal -> Dezimal*/
{
    int dezimalzahl = 0, i = 0;

    while (oktalzahl != 0)
    {
        dezimalzahl += (oktalzahl % 10) * pow(8, i);
        ++i;
        oktalzahl /= 10;
    }

    i = 1;

    return dezimalzahl;
}
```

Comment: You can accept the octal value as string and then extract the numerical part from it. Like ask user to input octal value with appending `0c` at start (say `0c12`). Then check if the input contains `0c`, if it contains these two characters proceed further, otherwise terminate.

Comment: Also you can check the input, if any `digit > 7` then it isn't an octal number.

Comment: do not use `pow` or other math functions when using integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would replace all the `scanf` and harcoded functions with `fgets` and `strtol`:

```
enum {oct = 8, dec = 10, hex = 16};

int to_number(int base, bool *match)
{
    char str[32];
    long num = 0;

    *match = false;
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
    {
        char *ptr;

        num = strtol(str, &ptr, base);
        *match = (*ptr == '\n'); // match is true if strtol stops scanning
                                 // at the newline left by fgets
    }
    return (int)num;
}

...

bool match;
int num = to_number(oct, &match);

printf("%d %s an octal\n", num, match ? "is" : "is not");
```

EDIT:

As pointed out by @klutt in comments, since `strtol` returns a `long`, ideally the function should also return `long` in order to avoid the cast, then, if you really need an `int`, you can cast the return of the function:

```
long to_number(int base, bool *match);

int num = (int)to_number(oct, &match);
```

Comment: I would put parenthesis around `*ptr == '\n'` just to be clear.

Comment: But why on earth are you declaring `num` as a long and then cast the result instead of changing the return type?

Comment: @klutt good point, I prefer avoiding them but I agree, is clearer

Comment: @klutt OP is working with `int`s in his example, why return a `long` if OP wants an `int`?

Comment: Ok, I see your point, but I would return long anyway. And I tend to see red when I see unnecessary casts. :)